# setting several scheduled Notifications in flutter doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I changed the id to a randomly generated number but still after I schedule one notification and then another one the first one won't be shown.

(I need these old versions because of other version issues)

flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.4+4

rxdart: ^0.24.1

This is the trigger:

```
     Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color:
                      colorChangeNotifyButton ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              child: MaterialButton(
                  child: Text("Notify me"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() =>
                        colorChangeNotifyButton = !colorChangeNotifyButton);
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
          child: MaterialButton(
              child: Text("Submit"),
              onPressed: () async {
                try {
                  if (task == null || task.length < 2) {
                    error(context, "Please add content");
                  } else {
                    colorChangeNotifyButton
                        ? null
                        : await localNotifiyManager.scheduleNotification(
                            selectedTime,
                            'Reminder:',
                            
                            task,
                            rng.nextInt(100000),
                            rng.nextInt(100000).toString()
                          );
                    print(colorChangeNotifyButton.toString());
                    setState(() => colorChangeNotifyButton = true);
                    print('test');
                    print(colorChangeNotifyButton.toString());
                  }
                } catch (e) {
                  error(context, e);
                }
```

And this is my LocalNotifyManager.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:rxdart/subjects.dart';

class LocalNotifyManager {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  var initSetting;
  BehaviorSubject<ReceivedNotification>
      get DidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject =>
          BehaviorSubject<ReceivedNotification>();

  LocalNotifyManager.init() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      requestIOSPermission();
    }
    initializePlatform();
  }

  requestIOSPermission() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        .requestPermissions(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
  }

  initializePlatform() {
    //TODO: need to fix with implementing Notifications for android
    var initSettingAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('100.png');
    var initSettingIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
        requestSoundPermission: true,
        requestAlertPermission: true,
        requestBadgePermission: true,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) async {
          ReceivedNotification notification = ReceivedNotification(
              id: id, title: title, body: body, payload: payload);
          DidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.add(notification);
        });
    initSetting = InitializationSettings(initSettingAndroid, initSettingIOS);
  }

  setOnNotificationReceive(Function onNotificationReceive) {
    DidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.listen((notification) {
      onNotificationReceive(notification);
    });
  }

  setOnNotificationClick(Function onNotificationClick) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetting,
        onSelectNotification: (String payload) async {
      onNotificationClick(payload);
    });
  }

   Future<void> scheduleNotification(DateTime scheduleNotificationDateTime, String title, String body, int id, String payload) async {
    var androidChannel = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'CHANNEL_ID', 'CHANNEL_NAME', 'CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION',
        importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High, playSound: true);

    var iosChannel = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannel = NotificationDetails(androidChannel, iosChannel);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
        id, title, body, scheduleNotificationDateTime, platformChannel,
        payload: payload);
  }

 
}

LocalNotifyManager localNotifiyManager = LocalNotifyManager.init();

class ReceivedNotification {
  ReceivedNotification({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.body,
    @required this.payload,
  });

  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String body;
  final String payload;
}
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue but in my case when I schedule multiple notifications for different days, all of them are showing up on the same day with a difference of a few hours. I setting timings as below: 
    var scheduledNotificationDateTime_1 = tztime.add(Duration(hours: 12));
    var scheduledNotificationDateTime_2 = tztime.add(Duration(days: 1));
    var scheduledNotificationDateTime_3 = tztime.add(Duration(days: 3));

Yet most of these notifications come on the same day

Comment: I just started implementing cloud functions at this point - however, if anyone finds out a solution would be grateful if you can post it here.